# Higher dimensional integral of linearly transformed radial functions

Tags: integration

Given a sufficiently smooth function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and a ball $B_r(x_0):=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\ |\ ||x-x_0||<r\}$ in the $n$-dimensional space, is there an explicit formula to compute
$$
\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)}g(||x||)dS(x)?
$$
I know that such integrals can be evaluated if the ball $B_r(x_0)$ is centered at $x_0=0$. Is there a similar formula for the general case?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Why don't you translate the ball by a simple linear transformation and use this special case?

Comment: Because then we have $g(||x-x_0||)$ under the integral sign, wich is not radial. The special case only talks about $\int_{\partial B_r(0)} g(||x||)dS(x)$.
Do I overlook anything trivial?

Comment: Ah yes, this definitely won't be $||x||$. No, I don't think you overlooked something trivial. Unless, of course, I did as well ;)